# Exposing a protected collection for LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I have a class which contains a generic dictionary:

```
protected Dictionary<K,T> Data { get; set;}
```

I wish to allow clients of this class to perform LINQ queries without having to return the Dictionary. I had look at `AsQueryable()` but that doesn't seems to do what I wish.

An example of the code I would like to write would be:

```
typeRepo.Query().Where( x => x.name == "wire")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the dictionary is holding a model (T) by its key (K). The code you'll need is:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query
{
    get { return Data.Values.AsQueryable(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a public property like that:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,T>> Query
{
    get { return Data.AsEnumerable(); }
}
```

and it should work like you expect.